# Combine videos after scale and rotate objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-processing

Here is my problem: I want to generate a video that contains parts from multiple videos. 
For videos created with back camera everything works fine but when I try to introduce a video from selfie camera, I have a black half of the screen. 
here is the code I use to rotate, scale, recenter the video. I think I have to apply other transforms too but I can't find what..

```
            CGAffineTransform orientationTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
            CGSize naturalSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize, orientationTransform);
            naturalSize.width = fabs(naturalSize.width);
            naturalSize.height = fabs(naturalSize.height);

            // Make sure the video is transformed properly - Apply Aspect Fill
            float scale = naturalSize.width < naturalSize.height ? _renderSize.width / naturalSize.width : _renderSize.height / naturalSize.height;

            CGPoint recenter;
            recenter.x = (_finalSize.width - naturalSize.width * scale) * 0.5;
            recenter.y = (_finalSize.height - naturalSize.height * scale) * 0.5;

            // If orientationTransform rotated the video in a way that changed the orientation, switch recenter
            if ((videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width > videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height) != (naturalSize.width > naturalSize.height)) {
                typeof(recenter.x) temp = recenter.x;
                recenter.x = recenter.y;
                recenter.y = temp;
            }    
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale),  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(recenter.x, recenter.y)), orientationTransform);

            [layerInstruction setTransform:transform atTime:timeOffset];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the transforms separately for the portrait ones and for the landscape ones.